# Group by min and fill NAs with value from another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a sample data frame that looks like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame (data = {'uid': [1,1,1,2,2,3], 'pagename':['home', 'blah', 
'blah', 'home', 'blah', 'blah'], 'startpage': ['NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'home', 
'home', 'blah'], 'date_time': [0,1,2,5,9,1]})
```

What I want to do is group by the UID and find the min date_time. If the startpage of the min date_time is Null (I put string 'NA' for Null) then I want to use the pagename from that row to populate the startpage column. I also want the startpage to be populated for all rows with the same UID.

This is the ending dataframe that I want.

```
df = pd.DataFrame (data = {'uid': [1,1,1,2,2,3], 'pagename':['home', 'blah', 
'blah', 'home', 'blah', 'blah'], 'startpage': ['home', 'home', 'home', 
'home', 'home', 'blah'], 'date_time': [0,1,2,5,9,1]})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fillna` with `transform`

```
i = df.groupby('uid').date_time.transform('idxmin')
df.startpage = df.startpage.fillna(i.map(df.pagename))

print(df)

   date_time pagename startpage  uid
0          0     home      home    1
1          1     blah      home    1
2          2     blah      home    1
3          5     home      home    2
4          9     blah      home    2
5          1     blah      blah    3
```

Comment: very interesting solution!