# Group by min and fill NAs with value from another column Part 2

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the original question:
[Group by min and fill NAs with value from another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43547600/group-by-min-and-fill-nas-with-value-from-another-column)

I have this dataframe:

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame (data = {'uid': [1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4], 'pagename':
['home', 'blah', 
'blah', 'home', 'blah', 'blah','blah','home','blah','blah'], 'startpage': 
[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'home', 
'home', 'blah',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan], 'date_time': 
[0,1,2,5,9,1,1,2,3,4], 'page_event': [0,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,10]})
```

I want to get this dataframe:

```
endingdf = pd.DataFrame (data = {'uid': [1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,4,4], 'pagename':
['home', 'blah', 'blah', 'home', 'blah','blah','blah','home','blah','blah'], 
'startpage': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'home', 
'home','blah',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
'date_time': [0,1,2,5,9,1,1,2,3,4], 'page_event': [0,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,10],
'new_start_page':['home', 'home', 'home', 'home', 'home', 'blah', 'home', 
'home', 'home', 'home']})
```

What I want to do is group by `UID` and if `startpage` is `NULL` then use the first `pagename` of the visit (min date_time) BUT only when `page_event = 0`. So if the first `pagename` has `page_event = 10` then skip that until `page_event = 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
e = mydf.page_event
p = mydf.pagename
s = mydf.startpage
u = mydf.uid
m = e.mask(e == 10).groupby(u).apply(pd.Series.first_valid_index)

s.fillna(u.map(m).map(p), inplace=True)

print(mydf)

   date_time  page_event pagename startpage  uid
0          0           0     home      home    1
1          1           0     blah      home    1
2          2           0     blah      home    1
3          5           0     home      home    2
4          9           0     blah      home    2
5          1           0     blah      blah    3
6          1          10     blah      home    4
7          2           0     home      home    4
8          3           0     blah      home    4
9          4          10     blah      home    4
```